# Switch case for cli arguments in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, command-line-interface

I'm grabbing CLI args via argc and argv in C. I'd like to use a switch case to do different things depending on the arguments passed. In my case, `cli u` will print "Updating..."

Here's what I've got so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  switch(argv[0]){
    case "t":
      printf("Updating...")
      break;
    default:
      printf("Welcome!")
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting `switch quantity not an integer` on `argv[0]`.

I'd like to use switch cases because this'll be a lengthy program. Thanks, and cheers!

Comment: You can't use a string as a switch case.

Comment: Use `strcmp` and an `if` statement. You can use chars in a switch statement though, if you know it's only a single letter, `switch (argv[0][0])` and `case 't':` or something like that. If you have a ton of different options consider using an array of functions, index into it and call the element at that index. Super clean way to refactor giant `switch`/`if` statements.

Comment: Also, `argv[0]` is the name of your program, do you mean `argv[1]`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah that explains it!

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you very much! I ended up using chars because I'm sure it'll be one character. I will most definitely look into using an array of functions in the future for this program!

Comment: Handling command-line arguments robustly is non-trivial. Unless your program takes exactly one argument, and it's a switch, you'll need to iterate the arguments, and probably the individual characters with the argument. You might need to handle cases where switches have arguments of their own. It's a useful exercise to write a command-line parser but, for production applications, it might be easier to use a well-established C function like `getopt()`  if it's available.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes I wasn't sure how that worked in C, so had to test it. I did indeed use argv[1][0] in the end though, so thanks!

Comment: @KevinBoone I'll have to look into getopt() more, but just as a pre-check, how much would this slow down a general program? I assume the speed is trvial, but I'm using characters for my arguments anyways, so I don't think I will personally need to switch to getopt this time. But, if the speed difference is super small (I mean like .5x less) I'll look into it!

Comment: @Bobbay -- I can't imagine there will be much difference in speed. There's no harm in parsing the command line yourself, and sometimes there are advantages. It's just not as straightforward as it might seem at first.

Comment: @KevinBoone Ok understandable. I'll stick with what I have at the moment but will look into getopt soon!